# AngularJS - Cannot read property of 'get' undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I am attempting to retrieve a dummy JSON file but I continually get the 'TypeError Cannot read property of 'get' undefined.

What appears to be the issue here?

Module:

```
angular.module('followup',['followupSearch']);
```

Factory:

```
angular.module('followup')
    .factory('followupStore', ['$http', function($http) {
        var followup = {};

        followup.getFollowup = function($http) {
            return $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        };

        return followup;
    }]);
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('followupSearch')
.controller('followupSearchCtrl', ['$http','followupStore',  function($http, followupStore) {

    var self = this;

    self.getFollowup = getFollowup;

        // Get followup
            function getFollowup() {
               followupStore.getFollowup()
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log('success');
                    }, function (error) {
                        console.log('error');
                    });
            } //getFollowup

}]);
```

Comment: `getFollowup` takes $http as input argument. remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the argument on the factory function. It will work because you already injected the `$http` service in the factory:

```
angular.module('followup')
    .factory('followupStore', ['$http', function($http) {
        var followup = {};

        followup.getFollowup = function() {
            return $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        };

        return followup;
}]);
```